# ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays

Tags: deep-learning, keras, classification

Using Keras DL library with Tensorflow backend, I'm attempting to extract features from the intermediate layer of VGG-16 to perform binary classification on my task of interest.

The data set contains 1000 (500 for each class) training samples and 200 (100 for each class) test samples. I'm training a small fully connected model on top of the extracted features. On running the code, I could see that the size of the train_data is (10000,6,6,512), validation_data is (2000,6,6,512) (float32), train_labels is (1000,2) and validation_labels is (200,2) (int32).

Here is the code:

```
########################load libraries#########################################
import numpy as np
import time
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras import applications
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#########################image characteristics#################################
img_rows=100 #dimensions of image, to be varied suiting the input requirements of the pre-trained model
img_cols=100
channel = 3 #RGB
num_classes = 2
batch_size = 10 
nb_epoch = 10
###############################################################################
''' This code uses VGG-16 as a feature extractor'''

feature_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 3))
#get the model summary
feature_model.summary()
#extract feature from the intermediate layer
feature_model = Model(input=feature_model.input, output=feature_model.get_layer('block5_conv2').output) 
#get the model summary
feature_model.summary()

#declaring image data generators

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'f1_100/train',
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,  
        shuffle=False)  

train_data = feature_model.predict_generator(generator, 1000)
train_labels = np.array([[1, 0]] * 500 + [[0, 1]] * 500)

generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'f1_100/test',
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)

validation_data = feature_model.predict_generator(generator, 200)
validation_labels = np.array([[1,0]] * 100 + [[0,1]] * 100)

###############################################################################
#addding the top layers and training them on the extracted features
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print('-'*30)
print('Start Training the top layers on the extracted features...')
print('-'*30)

#measure the time and train the model
t=time.time() 
hist = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, batch_size=batch_size,
                      validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels),
                      verbose=2)
#print the history of the trained model
print(hist.history)
print('Training time: %s' % (time.time()-t))
###############################################################################
```

However, on running the code, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-cc5b1b34cc67>", line 46, in <module>
    verbose=2)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 960, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1581, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1426, in _standardize_user_data
    _check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 250, in _check_array_lengths
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 10000 input samples and 1000 target samples.
```

Comment: train_labels should be (10000,2) and validation_labels should be (2000,2) matching your training data so that for each input you have an expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see, you have a batch_size of 10.

The `feature_model.predict_generator()` uses the `steps` param (in your case 1000) a total of 10 (batch_size) times. So a total of 10000 training samples are generated in that.

But in the next line, you are declaring the labels to be only 1000. (500 1s and 500 0s).

So you have two options:

1) Either change the `steps` in `predict_generator()` like this (which I believe is what you want, to generate 1000 samples in train and 200 samples in validation):

```
train_data = feature_model.predict_generator(generator, 100)
validation_data = feature_model.predict_generator(generator, 20)
```

2) Or you can change the numbers in labels:

```
train_labels = np.array([[1, 0]] * 5000 + [[0, 1]] * 5000)
validation_labels = np.array([[1,0]] * 1000 + [[0,1]] * 1000)
```